# error when trying to change language ODOO

Tags: javascript, python, erp, odoo-16

I tried to change the language from English to Portuguese and now the pages do not render. I tried to use "regenerate asset bundle" ", but it didn't work. got the following problem:

[image]

I tried to use "regenerate asset bundle"